# SQLServer choosing primary key type

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, sqldatatypes

I have a list of objects each of its own id and I need to create a table for them in a database. It's a good idea to use their ids(since they are unique) as a primary key in the table but there's one problem. All ids are integers except for the one object - it has 2 subobjects with ids `142.1` and `142.2`, so the id list is `140, 141, 142.1, 142.2, 143...`
Now if I choose a double as a type of primary key then it will store unnecessary 6 bytes(since double is 8 bytes and `INT` is 2) to only support two double numbers and I can't choose `INT`. So what type should I use if I cannot change the list of objects?

Comment: Not a good idea. You should never put logic into your primary keys. You should put the information about subobjects into a separate column.

Comment: `int` is 4 bytes not 2. (`smallint` is 2 though)

Comment: I know but I can't change anything right now, I need to solve this problem with what I have.

Comment: Martin, I looked at this table http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Comment: @Sergey - No idea of the accuracy of that table but it is for Microsoft Access not SQL Server anyway. [Refer to Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)  not w3schools for accurate information. `decimal(9,1)` [is 5 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: @Sergey, it says is 4 bytes on that website. you probably looked at the Access data types. SQL Server data types are almost at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Why do you care about the number of bytes of your PK? If that is an AccessDb then what are you afraid of? Even if you want to store 2 000 000 rows that's only 2mb of space for an extra byte - any computer can handle much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math for `double` is [imprecise](http://www.xkcd.com/217/), you shouldn't use it for discrete numbers like money or object id's.  Consider using [`decimal(p,s)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) instead.  Where `p` is the total number of digits, and `s` is the number of digits behind the dot.  For example, a `decimal(5,2)` could store `123.45`, but not `1234` or `12.345`.

Another option is a composite primary key for two integers `n1, n2`:

```
alter table YourTable add constraint PK_YourTable primary key (n1, n2)
```

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is four bytes, not two, so the size difference to a double is not so big.

However, you should definitely not use a floating point number as key, as a floating point number isn't stored as an exact values, but as an approximation.

You can use a `decimal` with one fractional digit, like `decimal(5,1)`, to store a value like that. A `decimal` is a fixed point number, so it's stored as an exact value, not an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Choose `VARCHAR` of an appropriate length, with `CHECK` constraints to ensure the data conforms to your domain rules e.g. based on the small sample data you posted:

```
CREATE TABLE Ids 
(
 id VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    CONSTRAINT id__pattern
       CHECK (
              id LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
              OR id LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9].[1-9]'
             )
);
```